# Have I reached the maximum limit of iframes per page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is there a way of displaying more than 1000 iframes per page? I thought there were no upper limit, but I seem to have found it.

I am developing a hybrid mobile app where I display iframes upon request. These iframes are held within numbered spans from 1 to 1200. However, when spans bigger than 1000 are requested, the iframes are not displayed.

Let me illustrate with some code:

```
    <span id="1000" style="display:none;">
        <br><br><br>
        <span style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:70%;-webkit-filter: blur(5px);-moz-filter: blur(5px);-o-filter: blur(5px);-ms-filter: blur(5px);filter: blur(5px);">
            <iframe style="border-radius:12px" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/tracktokenhere1"
                width="100%" height="152" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen=""
                allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture"
                loading="lazy"></iframe>
        </span><br>
        <div class="flip3D" onclick="flipCard()" style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <div class="card">
                  <!-- This content is always displayed when requested -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span id="1001" style="display:none;">
        <br><br><br>
        <span style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:70%;-webkit-filter: blur(5px);-moz-filter: blur(5px);-o-filter: blur(5px);-ms-filter: blur(5px);filter: blur(5px);">
            <iframe style="border-radius:12px" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/tracktokenhere2"
                width="100%" height="152" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen=""
                allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture"
                loading="lazy"></iframe>
        </span><br>
        <div class="flip3D" onclick="flipCard()" style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <div class="card">
                  <!-- This content is always displayed when requested -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
```

So, when I request the span id="1000" I see the Spotify content without any problem. However, when I request id="1001" I can see the rest of the content of the span, but the iframe content is missing.

At first, I thought that there were something in the id="1001" that was wrong, but I commented out the id="1000" and the id="1001" became 'visible'. So I concluded that there is a maximum limit on the iframes display.

How can I get rid of this limit?

I have no problems on loading time, I have that fixed.

Comment: Is this behavior true on all the different browsers you've tried? Also, nesting `<div>` elements inside `<span>` doesn't really make sense; `<span>` elements are for inline content, while `<div>` elements are blocks.

Comment: Good catch. This limitation applies to Chrome and Edge, not Mozilla Firefox though. However, it is limited when running this as a hybrid app on a mobile. That's why I wonder how to surpass this limitation.

Comment: Well if the browsers don't want to do it, I'm not sure what you can do. I have to say, 1000 frames on a single page does not seem like the best user experience.

Comment: divs and iframes in spans are invalid HTML

Comment: So, you think that if I modify that the limitation will be gone? I am not interested in accurate and academic HTML, but functional.

Comment: I give up. I tried many things: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/w8fnqy54/

Comment: Not helpful here but slightly amusing: [link](https://what.thedailywtf.com/topic/25091/chrome-only-allows-1000-iframes). "if you run up against this limit, your design is very wrong and should be revisited."